# Does the Stack Overflow API support the ability to get questions that are Active or Hot?

Tags: support, api, stack-overflow-enterprise

Does the Stack Overflow API support the ability to GET questions that are Active or Hot?

Obviously the **Top Questions** page groups questions onto tabs by *Active*, *Hot*, *Week* and *Month*. Each of these views can be accessed in the browser, and through RSS feeds, but I do not see them in the [Stack Overflow API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

And the **All Questions** page adds *Newest*, *Frequent*, *Votes* and *Unanswered*. The API provides an endpoint for `questions/no-answers` and `questions/unanswered`, but not the others.

I have checked the public API docs as well as those on our internal Stack Overflow Enterprise.

Those API routes would be very useful for programmatically promoting the *Hot* and *Active* questions internally, to draw in more employee users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For "Active" questions,** almost every route supports sorting by `last_activity_date` (Descending).

For example: [/2.2/posts?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), which shows the most recently active *posts* first.

**For "Hot" questions,** the `/questions` route and [the `/me/tags/{tags}/top-questions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-tags-top-questions) have this as an optional sorting. (No clue why it's only available on just those two<sup>‡</sup>.)

> [image: hot sorting]

For example, [/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=hot&tagged=support&site=meta.stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=hot&tagged=support&filter=!LH2E98MvwFnJm2d)SgcF3H&site=meta.stackoverflow&run=true) currently returns results like:

```
{ "items": [ {
      "tags": ["support", "election", "faq-proposed"],
      "owner": { "display_name": "JL2210" },
      "is_answered": false,
      "view_count": 23,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "score": -5,
      "last_activity_date": 1566941318,
      "creation_date": 1566940698,
      "last_edit_date": 1566941318,
      "question_id": 388959,
      "link": "https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388959/how-do-moderator-elections-work",
      "title": "How do moderator elections work?"
    }, {
      "tags": ["support", "feature-request", "api", "so-enterprise"],
      "owner": { "display_name": "5eleven7" },
      "is_answered": false,
      "view_count": 22,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "score": 4,
      "last_activity_date": 1566938483,
      "creation_date": 1566938483,
      "question_id": 388957,
      "link": "https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388957/does-the-stack-overflow-api-support-the-ability-to-get-questions-that-are-active",
      "title": "Does the Stack Overflow API support the ability to get questions that are Active or Hot?"
    },
    // ...
```

---

<sup>‡</sup> It's possible that that sorting may work on other routes and is just not documented.  Haven't tested it (and never had the need).

Comment: Excellent thank you. I was expecting to see them as specific routes, but you helped me understand they are sort options.